# Is there any way to load dynamic data in dynamic form using SQL PHP JS?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I tried to load forms dynamically from SQL. I  succeded to load the form. but inside the form, there is an option to select a category which will be dynamically loaded into that from. But I failed to load it in the form.

> PATIENT AND CATEGORY TOTALLY SEPARATED TABLE

**HTML:**

```
   <tbody>
       <?php
          foreach ($patients as $patient) {

             echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td>" . $patient["id"] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $patient["full_name"] . "</td>";
             echo "<td >" . $patient["phone"] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $patient["email"] . "</td>";
             echo "<td>" . $patient["service"]  . "</td>";
             echo "<td>";
             echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-primary editPatient_btn' id=" . $patient["id"] . ">Edit</button>";
             echo "</td>";
             echo "</tr>";
             } ?>
   </tbody>



<form action="" method="post">
      <div class="patient_details">
      </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     <button type="submit" name="admin_patient_edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**AJAX JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".editPatient_btn").click(function() {
            var patient_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                url: "../../controller/Controller.php",
                method: "post",
                data: {
                    patient_id: patient_id,
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    //console.log(patient_id);
                    $('.patient_details').html(data);
                    $("#exampleEditModalLongpatient").modal("show");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**PHP:**

```
if (isset($_POST["patient_id"])) {
    $output = '';
    editPatient($_POST["patient_id"]);
}

function editPatient($patient_id)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='$patient_id'";
    $patient_details = getArray($query);
    $output = '
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $patient_details["id"] . '">
    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" id="edit_name" type="text" name="name" value="' . $patient_details["full_name"] . '" placeholder="Patient Name" required>
    <br>
    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" id="edit_mail" type="email" name="email" value="' . $patient_details["email"] . '" placeholder="Email Address" required>
    <br>
    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" id="edit_tel" type="tel" name="tel" value="' . $patient_details["phone"] . '" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
    <br> 
<select class="form-control patient_category_selector" name="patient_category" value="' . $patient_details["category"] . '" id="doctor_category_selector" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
     <?php
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if($category["category_name"]==' . $patient_details["category"] . '){
            echo "<option selected>" . $category["category_name"] . "</option>";
       }
        else{
        echo "<option>" . $category["category_name"] . "</option>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>      
    ';
    echo $output;
}
```

so I want to load category in selector as name, email, and tel works. So, is there any way to load that category in option dynamically?

Comment: The `foreach` should not be part of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. I didn't use datatype json previously. JSON is the solution for showing dynamic values in dynamic forms [multi dynamic data].

the script should look like this-

**AJAX JS:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".editPatient_btn").click(function() {
            var patient_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                url: "../../controller/Controller.php",
                method: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    patient_id: patient_id,
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#patient_id').val(data.id);
                    $('#edit_name').val(data.full_name);
                    $('#edit_mail').val(data.email);
                    $('#edit_tel').val(data.phone);
                    $('#edit_patient_category').val(data.category);
                    $("#exampleEditModalLongpatient").modal("show");

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
    <form action="" method="post">
                                <div class="patient_details">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="patient_id" value="">
                                    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" id="edit_name" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Patient Name" required>
                                    <br>
                                    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" id="edit_mail" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                                    <br>
                                    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" id="edit_tel" type="tel" name="tel" value="" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
                                    <br>
<select class="form-control patient_category_selector" name="patient_category" id="edit_patient_category" value="" id="doctor_category_selector" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
     <?php
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if($category["category_name"]==' . $patient_details["category"] . '){
            echo "<option selected>" . $category["category_name"] . "</option>";
       }
        else{
        echo "<option>" . $category["category_name"] . "</option>";
        }
    }
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="submit" name="admin_patient_edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

**PHP should look like this:**

```
if (isset($_POST["patient_id"])) {
    $output = '';
    editPatient($_POST["patient_id"]);
}
function editPatient($patient_id)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='$patient_id'";
    $patient_details = getArray($query);

    echo json_encode($patient_details);
}
```